# Too slow celery restart

Tags: python, celery

I actively use delayed tasks, so have about 6000 task in RabbitMQ queue.
When celery workers restart in debug log appears ~6000 entries:

```
INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery.task_name
[4026841c-1d3a-4097-9e43-39b0b81b7b23] eta:[2016-08-11 10:54:16.179000+03:00]
```

Because of large count of registered tasks celery workers can't process new realtime tasks which stay delayed for about 10-15 minutes(approx. current celery restart time).

How can I accelerate restart process?

Answer (score 0):

add `--purge` to your restart command to clear the queue first

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want clear my queue, these tasks are useful for me.